# Z3PY equation, size limitation

Tags: python, math, z3, z3py

I'm working on Z3PY i would like to know how to limit the size of the calculation of a equation

```
    v0 = Int('v0')
    const = 0x12345678
    I wrote this : 
s.add( (const*(v0 + const*(func(v0*const) - v0)) - v0) == somevalueof64bits)
```

my problem is that the calculation of '(const*(v0 + const*(func(v0*const) - v0)) - v0)' is bigger than 64 bits

Answer (score 1):

Integers in Z3 (and generally in SMT solvers) are not bounded by machine integer representations. Under the hood it uses big-integer representations that allow calculating with arbitrary size integers.